# CVS and Visual Studio 2008 - integration options

Tags: visual-studio, cvs, integration

I'd like to increase developers' "comfort level" in our team a bit.
We are using Visual Studio 2008 and TortoiseCVS + WinCVS, but no integration as of yet.

In your CVS/Visual Studio experience, what is the best integration tool in terms of "supports basic CVS functionality add/diff/update/commit/annotate/etc", "works out of the box", almost "bug-free"?

- a) commercial
- b) free or open source

---

#### Edit:

There are 2 commercial MSSCCI bridge solutions I've found so far: PushOk.com and TamTam (daveswebsite.com). Both were developed quite a long time ago and now have only minor updates. Being MSSCCI bridges, they are somewhat limited in functionality and can not provide all the nice features of vsPackage SCC provider, but are probably better than nothing.

Comment: We've been using CVS for three years and still haven't found something useful...

Comment: thanks for the input, Bob.
guess we'll see if I get frustrated enough to write a package for it ;)

Comment: I was using SVN in my previous job, but now I'm stuck with CVS. I never felt a need for integration to Visual Studio, but in three years I wasn't even able to find a good client for it. WinCVS is horrible, TortoiseCVS is decent, but has too many flaws to be good. Naturally, I started working on my own client, but after I solved a major pain point for me (quick diffing), I rarely find time for improvements :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be stuck with one of those MSSCCI bridges you mentioned. As it is, not too many people still use CVS, especially those using Visual Studio (most of them seem to use Team System's revision control, or Subversion).

There's always the possibility of hacking together your own macros to take care of CVS operations, but this has the disadvantage of not giving you real, in-depth integration the way a an SCC provider, or even an old brige, would.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CVS, but if going to SVN is an option, there's always [Ankh](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, CodeRot.
Unfortunately there is a requirement to use CVS.

Comment: I'm actually not liking Ankh, I setup a bunch of my own macros with right click options in the solution explorer and toolbar buttons to handle SVN.  I'm sure the same type of stuff could be set up for CVS since, I'm sure you can do command line stuff.

Comment: Did you try AnkhSVN 1.X (The old AddIn) or AnkhSVN 2.0 (The new SCC VAPI Package implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Ankh is a open source choice

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Comment: I believe, there is no Ankh for CVS :(

Comment: hmm, i was to triggerhappy there it seems, did distinguish cvs and subversion, sorry bout that.